# Disconnect VBA UserForm from parent application

Tags: api, vba, excel, userform

I'm using a UserForm spawned by Excel that modifies a PowerPoint presentation (it's a roundabout way to avoid needing a macro-enabled spreadsheet). The form works just fine, but every time I focus to it the Excel application takes focus (since Excel is the parent window).

Is there any way to stop this from happening? I'd like to prevent Excel from taking focus when the UserForm is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?  This will hide/make invisible the parent Excel Application while the UserForm is displayed.  Or at least get you started:

Example subroutine that "Shows" the userform:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ppt As Object
Dim xl As Object
Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Use this in the form's `Terminate` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    'Ensures the Excel Application is visible after the form closes
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

You could add a button/etc on the form, if you want to allow the user to unhide the Excel Application

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Displays the Excel Application:
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's close. Since I want the form to be able to interact with both applications (depending on the task), I think this might work a little. I can put code to hide excel when explicitly working with powerpoint and vice versa. It will be tricky though, one of the things this form does is take a selection in Excel and paste it into the presentation, so we'll see how far I get.

Comment: Right, well, you can use the form's other event handlers to determine when/whether to make Excel `.Visible=True`.  You can also resize the Excel window.  Or, probably the best way to do it would be to rewrite your macro so that it is launched from within PPT, rather than from Excel.  This way it will always have focus, but you can still interact with Excel.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid making the presentation a macro-enabled one, since the spreadsheet I'm launching already is macro enabled. The tool is meant to be an overlay to the presentation during data manipulation, but I think the hiding thing should work OK. :)

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a PPT Add-In instead of a PPTM, that way it is truly an overlay.

Comment: +1 I shamelessly copied `Application.Visible = True`

Comment: In fact i deleted my post because it is very similar to yours... I would recommend that you suggest the `vbmodeless` part. No point both of us suggesting hte same thing :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I added `vbModeless` but assumed that OP was doing that already, since the form relies on a cells `Selection`.  But I will add it just to be sure :)

Comment: I think the .Visible property will probably be the way to go, I just have to make it more obvious how to get back when the user is done with the tool. Thanks!

Comment: Tie it to the `UserForm_Terminate` event? otherwise you could make do some custom event handling/class objects/etc. or something but the built-in form events should probably be enough.

Comment: I used a little craftiness. Using a Tab control, I tied the application.visible property to the tabchange event and it works nicely. :)